# What is the difference between installing apache from "yum install httpd" and "source"?

Tags: linux, apache

1) What is the difference between installing apache from "yum install httpd" and "source" ?
2) Why both installation methods create different path for httpd.conf file?
3) Are we doing source installations for specific requirements?

### Installation from Source:

> tar xvfz httpd-2.2.17.tar.gz --> ./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --> make --> make install

### Installation using YUM:

> yum instll httpd

Please help me.

Thanks in advance
-Shishir

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What is the differnce between installing apache from "yum install
>   httpd" and "source" ?

Installing distributor-provided package (eg. by `yum`) means installing precompiled, almost-ready-to-use binary version of application, whereas installation by source means building application from source, which involves compiling program source code into binary code.

Most notable differences are:

1. Building from source provides more flexibility - often applications can be configured to be built with different features. For example, you can decide whether you want to build Apache with support for SSL and whether you want to include support for PHP scripting and so on. On the other hand, binary packages are sometimes split into several packages, for example Apache modules (such as `mod_php`) can be installed as separate modules.
2. Installing from source is usually much more time consuming while installing binary package involves mainly copying files and running installation scripts.
3. Most often, latest versions of applications are provided in source form only - there is time gap before application is packaged and made available in repositories. On the other hand, application installed from repository will be automatically updated by package manager, while applications installed from source will have to be updated manually.
4. Installing binary packages need only package manager, whareas installing from source required working toolchain, mostly `make`, compilers (eg. `gcc`) and development version of third-party libraries.
5. Package manager handles dependencies for you. For example, Apache needs `libapr`, Apache Portable Runtime. When you install Apache using package manager, it installs `libapr` automatically for you. When you build from source, you have to install `libapr` first.

> 2) Why both installation methods create different path for httpd.conf
>   file?

Because different distributions have different guidelines for filesystem layout. RedHat packages follow RedHat guidelines, Debian packages follow Debian guidelines.

Source packages follow some "generic" guidelines.

> 3) Are we doing source installations for specific requirements?

That may be one reason for doing so. See point 1.

Comment: Thanks a tone for your reply... It helped me a lot. I have few more doubts, could you please clarify?

1) Different distributions can use same Source to install Apache (Example:httpd-2.2.17.tar.gz) or whatever ??

2) What are the advantages of using Source when there are some challenges to use it?